# Using liquid to sort posts by the latest date(latest(posted_date, updated_date))

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm writing a site in Jekyll, which uses Liquid.

I have ymal for pages , like this:

```
---
title: Mytitle
posted: 2020-06-29
updated: 2020-07-29
....
---
```

And I have some posts, as follows

```
{
title: title1
posted: 2020-06-29
updated: 2020-07-29
},
{
title: title2
posted: 2020-07-05
},
{
title: title 3
posted: 2020-07-01
updated: 2020-07-20
},
{
title: title 4
posted: 2020-07-22
},
```

I expect the order of posts which is sorted by the latest date, i.e. `latest(posted, updated)`.

liquid seems cannot sort by custom function? Can someone tell me what to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

By default `site.posts` are sorted by the `date` property (newest fist), which you called `posed`. So you may want to rename it to `date` to make your life easier.

For custom sorting you can use the Liquid [sort filter](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/sort/), which takes **one** argument.

So if you want to sort by `updated` instead, you can do that with:

```
{% assign my_sorted_list = site.posts | sort:"updated" %}
{% for post in my_sorted_list %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

You'll need to set the `updated` property then for every post or use a custom hook as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36758072/how-to-insert-the-last-updated-time-stamp-in-jekyll-page-at-build-time).

Comment: Thank you Jens .  Before posting the question,  I tried sort by `updated`.  However the result did not meet my expectations.  In my case,  I expect get   `title1 -> title4 -> title3 -> title2` ,  but got `title1 -> title3 -> title4 -> title2`. I kown I can add `updated` whitch value is same as `posted`   in `title4` and `title2`  to fix this question.  But I am interested in that can liquid  sort by  a custom compare function,, like a function like [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63149457/changing-a-variablestring-in-a-class-in-python/63149652#63149652)?

Comment: No, liquid doesn't provide such a function. Would be nice though.